# Can a Python program query LC_CTYPE locale settings?

Tags: python, locale

In C++ (and C) you can use the functions in [<cwctype>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cwctype) to query LC_CTYPE character classes for a given character in the active locale.

Is there a way to access these options in Python? **Specifically, can I test whether a given character is blank in the active locale?**

Basically, I want a Python equivalent of this C++ example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cwctype>
#include <clocale>

// From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswblank

int main()
{
    wchar_t c = L'\u3000'; // Ideographic space ('　')
 
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << "in the default locale, iswblank(" << (std::wint_t)c << ") = "
              << (bool)std::iswblank(c) << '\n';
    // output: in the default locale, iswblank(0x3000) = false

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::cout << "in Unicode locale, iswblank(" << (std::wint_t)c << ") = "
              << (bool)std::iswblank(c) << '\n';
    // output: in Unicode locale, iswblank(0x3000) = true
}
```

I have not been able to find a way to do this in Python. The [locale module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) provides many functions, but seems to completely miss LC_CTYPE queries.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There is no Python equivalent to `<cwctype>` that I am aware of. But ...

Longer answer:

Python focuses on localisation rather than internationalisation so locale based functions that are exposed in Python focus on the needs of localisation. Additionally, there are a number of different implementations of libc, and locale data can vary between implementations.

The logic in `(bool)std::iswblank(c)` seems to be: test if the character (c) is whitespace, returning a boolean result.

Python3 by default uses Unicode, all strings are Unicode strings. There is one exception to this, the C locale only supports ASCII.

So `iswblank()` for the C locale testing if c is a space or a horizontal tab. For other locales, it is testing if the character, c, is whitespace based on the encoding that the locale is using. For locales in Python, this would be anything classed as whitespace by Unicode. I assume in a non-C locale what you need to test for is any character that is a whitespace character that is invisible, but does take up space. This would be any character with the Unicode property Space_Separator (Zs).

It is possible to use `c.isspace()`, the regex pattern `\p{Zs}` or the unicodedata module: `unicodedata.category(c) == 'Zs'`. The code fragments below allow you to specify a locale category. And a test should be added, to ensure `len(char) == 1`.

1.

```py
def is_whitespace(char, locale_category=locale.LC_CTYPE):
    if locale.getlocale(locale_category)[0] == None:
        return True if char in ['\u0009', '\u0020'] else False
    return char.isspace()
```

2. 

```py
import regex
def is_whitespace_regex(char, locale_category=locale.LC_CTYPE):
    if locale.getlocale(locale_category)[0] == None:
        return True if char in ['\u0009', '\u0020'] else False
    return bool(regex.match(r'\p{Zs}', char))
```

3. 

```py
import unicodedata
def is_whitespace_ud(char, locale_category=locale.LC_CTYPE):
    if locale.getlocale(locale_category)[0] == None:
        return True if char in ['\u0009', '\u0020'] else False
    return True if unicodedata.category(char) == 'Zs' else False
```

This approach appears to follow the intention of the c/C++ function.